# Tomcat login error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, forms-authentication

I'm trying to develop an web app using java. I was using apache tomcat 7 and it was working fine. But today I installed tomcat 8. Then I transferred my web app to the new installation of apache. But now, I can't login to the web app.

Here is my `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="manager" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

When I tried to access the login example of the apache tomcat using the user name `tomcat` and password `tomcat`, it directs to the error page. It says,

> Invalid username and/or password, please try again.

Can any one tell me where the error is ?

Comment: "Can any one tell me where the error is ?" Yes: you don't have a user `tomacat`.

Comment: Exactly! You have a user called `tomcat`, not `tomacat`.